# For-Loop Index KeyError when trying to get sums

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, keyerror

I want to find out the SUM of a variable for a specific classification. My variable a is a (CM) classification, the other one is a float (zahlgesnet). I'm getting an Error I cannot really recognize myself whats it about.

This is actually to calculate the sums of a confusion Matrix Output. I tried so far to use different methods but I want to know why this Method is not working. Since I'm python beginner, I'm not sure if this Method is overall suitable.

This is how the Data Looks like:

```py
  ID zahlgesnet CM 

1 1  2.234,42   0
3 2  0          3
4 3  234        0
6 4  8.234      2
7 5  653,23     1  
9 6  134        2
```

And this is my Code:

```py
SummeFF = 0
SummeFT = 0
SummeTF = 0
SummeTT = 0
result = 0

def getsums(x,y,z,v):
    for i in range(len(X_valid)):
        if X_valid.CM[i] == 0:
            x += (X_valid.zahlgesnet[i])
        elif X_valid.CM[i] == 1:
            y += (X_valid.zahlgesnet[i])
        elif X_valid.CM[i] == 2:
            z += (X_valid.zahlgesnet[i])
        elif X_valid.CM[i] == 3:
            v += (X_valid.zahlgesnet[i])

getsums(SummeFF,SummeFT,SummeTF,SummeTT)            
print(SummeFF,SummeFT,SummeTF,SummeTT)
```

I expected that the function itinerates trough all the values and gives four different sums back, based on the classificator CM.

The Error I get is:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-788203eee12b> in <module>
     20 
     21 
---> 22 getsums(SummeFF,SummeFT,SummeTF,SummeTT)
     23 print(SummeFF,SummeFT,SummeTF,SummeTT)
     24 

<ipython-input-40-788203eee12b> in getsums(x, y, z, v)
      7 def getsums(x,y,z,v):
      8     for i in range(len(X_valid)):
----> 9         if X_valid.CM[i] == 0:
     10             x += (X_valid.zahlgesnet[i])
     11         elif X_valid.CM[i] == 1:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1066         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   1067         try:
-> 1068             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1069 
   1070             if not is_scalar(result):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4728         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4729         try:
-> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4731         except KeyError as e1:
   4732             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 2
```

Does it have something to do with the Index of my Dataframe is not following 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10? Is there a way to fix it? It resulted out of a lot of slicing of the dataframe before. Thanks a lot already!

Comment: can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is one of these is what you need?

```
df.groupby('CM')['zahlgesnet'].transform('sum')
```

**Output**

```
1    2.234,42234
3              0
4    2.234,42234
6       8.234134
7         653,23
9       8.234134
```

```
df.groupby('CM')['zahlgesnet'].sum()
```

**output**

```
CM
0    2.234,42234
1         653,23
2       8.234134
3              0
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do then you can simply use groupby:

```
X_valid.groupby(['CM'])['zahlgesnet'].sum()
```

As for your code, try:

```
SummeFF = 0
SummeFT = 0
SummeTF = 0
SummeTT = 0
result = 0

def getsums(x,y,z,v):
    for i in range(len(X_valid)):
        if X_valid.iloc[i].CM == 0:
            x += (X_valid.iloc[i].zahlgesnet)
        elif X_valid.iloc[i].CM == 1:
            y += (X_valid.iloc[i].zahlgesnet)
        elif X_valid.iloc[i].CM == 2:
            z += (X_valid.iloc[i].zahlgesnet)
        elif X_valid.iloc[i].CM == 3:
            v += (X_valid.iloc[i].zahlgesnet)

getsums(SummeFF,SummeFT,SummeTF,SummeTT)            
print(SummeFF,SummeFT,SummeTF,SummeTT)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first method works fine. Still for your idea of my Code I do get the same error. Do you have a conclusion why there is this keyError?

Comment: @Changer Yes, you need to use [integer-location based indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html). I updated the answer, it should work now